# Can't Install Plugins with WP CLI

Tags: wordpress

I'm not able to install plugins using the WP CLI. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running a local WordPress site using MAMP on Windows 10. I'm using the WP CLI on Ubuntu terminal which is runs on VirtualBox on my Windows 10 machine.

In Ubuntu terminal when I try running `wp plugin install jetpack` I get the error message below:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory 
in /home/matt-j/windows-desktop/projects/wp-rest-api-with-js/wp-includes/wp- 
db.php on line 1531
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in 
/home/matt-j/windows-desktop/projects/wp-rest-api-with-js/wp-includes/wp- 
db.php on line 1531
Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the 
username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect 
or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your 
host’s database server is down.
```

Comment: its clearly showing that username or password or database name is wrong

Comment: This either means that the 
username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect 
or it can’t contact the database server at `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get WP-CLI working with MAMP on Windows and Ubuntu that is installed on VirtualBox on Windows. So instead I:

1. Installed XAMPP on Ubuntu that lives on VirtualBox on Windows.
2. Changed the document root of XAMPP to point to my Windows directory by going to `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` and editing `httpd.conf` so that `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"` and `Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs"` are edited to `DocumentRoot "/home/matt-j/windows-desktop/apfm/repos`" and `Directory "/home/matt-j/windows-desktop/apfm/repos"` (**NOTE**: `windows-desktop` is my alias for my Desktop on my Windows 10 host).
3. Then I added the code below in my Ubuntu `.profile` file:

`# Define path for XAMPP`

`XAMPP_PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:/opt/lampp/sbin`

`export PATH="$XAMPP_PATH:$PATH"`

4. Then I reloaded the `.profile` file by doing `source ~/.profile` in the Ubuntu Terminal.
5. Finally I then navigate to the directory in Ubuntu Terminal of my WordPress install (like `~/windows-desktop/apfm/repos/mj_local_test_wp`) and can successfully run WP CLI commands (like `wp plugin install jetpack`).

I hope this helps someone!